Count the number of records that fall within 10-year time intervals
I ran a location in Verisk Touchstone and would like to see how many hurricane events (records) occur on average every 10 years.
I could figure this out by running the following script (see below) for each 10 year period in my output but this would take ages. Do you know if there is anyway to automate this/do this all at once? Hopefully I'm making some sense...
select *
from [dbo].[t1_HAZ_Intensity]
where YearID<=10
 
select *
from [dbo].[t1_HAZ_Intensity]
where YearID>=10 and YearID<=20

select *
from [dbo].[t1_HAZ_Intensity]
where YearID>=20 and YearID<=30
 

...etc
I've tried running the following code but this would take ages given that there are 2000 years in the event catalogue
select *
from [dbo].[t1_HAZ_Intensity]
where YearID<=10
 
select *
from [dbo].[t1_HAZ_Intensity]
where YearID>=10 and YearID<=20

select *
from [dbo].[t1_HAZ_Intensity]
where YearID>=20 and YearID<=30

....

Does this answer your question? Group rows by Year Band Interval

A [mre] with sample data and desired results make questions much easier to answer.

you can calculate the decades and use them to GROUP BY
SELECT COUNT(*) as [count], CONCAT(decade, '-', decade + 9) as [year]
FROM (SELECT FLOOR(YearID / 10) * 10 as decade
      FROM [dbo].[t1_HAZ_Intensity]) t
GROUP BY decade

or as CTE
WITH CTE AS (SELECT FLOOR(YearID / 10) * 10 as decade
          FROM [dbo].[t1_HAZ_Intensity])
SELECT COUNT(*) as [count], CONCAT(decade, '-', decade + 9) as [year]
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY decade

